# How to loop through an object in VB .NET?

Tags: .net, serialization, xml-deserialization

I am using (de)serialization to work with XML files in VB.Net

I have been able to convert an encrypted XML file to an object using the following code:

```
Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(xmlObj.GetType, xRoot)
xmlObj = serializer.Deserialize(reader)
fs.Close()
```

I now want to run my decrypt function (`Dcr(string)`) on each property (correct term?) in the object, so that the object (or a new object if necessary) contains the decrypted string values.

Comment: You're looking for Reflection.  However, consider encrypting the XML instead.

Comment: The XML is encrypted?

Comment: I mean decrypting the XML instead.

Comment: In my project, the XML tag names are uncrypted, it is only the values that are encrypted. Would this not be the best way to approach it, with this in mind?

Comment: No; just parse the XML and decrypt the values.